# Calculate an area using property method in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python3 and I have created the following class to get and return the height and width of a rectangle:

```
lass rectangle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.height = 0
        self.width = 0
    def set_size(self, size):
        self.width, self.height = size
    def get_size(self, size):
        return self.width, self.height

    size = property(get_size, set_size)
```

However, I also want to add another attribute `area` that returns simply the area of the rectangle using property function. So I tried the following:

```
class rectangle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.height = 0
        self.width = 0
    def set_size(self, size):
        self.width, self.height = size
    def get_size(self, size):
        return self.width, self.height
    def area(self, size):
        self.width * self.height = area


    size = property(get_size, set_size,area)

r = rectangle()
r.width = 6
r.height = 10
r.size = 7, 10
print(r.area)
```

However, when I tried test in the console it would give me this error:

```
self.width * self.height = area
    ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to operator
```

Would much appreciate a fix with some explanation. Thanks!

Comment: `self.area = self.width * self.height`? Or `return self.width * self.height`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mixed up the assignment value

```
class rectangle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.height = 0
        self.width = 0
    def set_size(self, size):
        self.width, self.height = size
    def get_size(self, size):
        return self.width, self.height
    @property
    def area(self):
        area = self.width * self.height 
        return area
    
    size = property(get_size, set_size,area)

r = rectangle()
r.width = 6
r.height = 10
r.size = 7, 10
print(r.area)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your LHS value should be in RHS value and vice versa:

`area = self.width * self.height`